# How to report connected printer in GCP as online printer

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-print

I'm writing a connector-base software to register legacy printers + receive print jobs from `GCP`, I have successfully registered and authorized my printer to `GCP` using [`/register`](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/proxyinterfaces#register) call.

Now, i want to make my printer status as online in `GCP` printers list(which is now offline):

[image]

I did this with [`/update`](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/proxyinterfaces#update) call with the `semantic_state` parameter and following [CDS](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/cdd#cds) data:

```
{
    "printer": {
        "state": "IDLE"
    },
    "version": "1.0"
}
```

But that doesn't resolve the issue! AND also `cloud_connection_state` field is suppose to be set by the server.

So which API should i use ?!

Answer (score 0):

In order to put a *registered* printer in online status, we need to make a persistent `XMPP` connection flow to `talk.google.com`.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/rawxmpp) is the connection handshake detail from google